# Using DEoptim() function from RcppDE package in C++ source file

Tags: r, rcpp

Is there any way how to call `DEoptim()` function from RcppDE package in C++ source file?

I'm trying to use:

```
//[[Rcpp::depends(RcppDE)]]
```

but have no idea if it is correct or not. And if it is, what should I do further?

Comment: When I try to call `DEoptim()` I get a message _error: use of undeclared identifier 'DEoptim' _. There is the simplest version of my code:

`#include <Rcpp.h>`
`using namespace Rcpp;`
`// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppDE)]]`
`// [[Rcpp::export]]`
`double opt(Function fun) {
  return DEoptim(fun, -1, 1);
}

`

Comment: I'm not familiar with the package but from a glance at the [repository](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/rcppde) it does not look like API is exposed on the C++ level. For example, [the source code](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/rcppde/blob/master/src/deoptim.cpp#L24-L89) for the exported *R* function `DEoptim` does not appear to be callable from C++, as far as I can tell at least. For this to be the case, typically the package's header files would be present in the `inst/` sub-directory so that they are installed on your machine.

Comment: I understand. Thank you for your comments. Do you know any ways how to do numerical optimization from the C++ side?

Comment: In general, or using the `DEoptim` function specifically?

Comment: My problem is the following. I'm writing a cpp function I would like to call from R. I need to do numerical optimization inside this cpp function. I thought that `DEoptim()` would help. As I understand from the upper comments, it cannot be possible. So the question is: how can it be resolved?

Comment: Well, for the reasons discussed above it's not possible to use `DEoptim` via `// [[Rcpp::depends(DEOptim)]]`, but like I said the C++ source code for the function is [available here](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/rcppde/blob/master/src/deoptim.cpp#L24-L89), so why not just copy that code into your project / source file(s), etc.? It's still a valid C++ function; you just don't need to `// [[Rcpp::export]]` it since you will not be calling it from R.

Comment: Ok. I understand. Thank you very much for your help!